# Using dapper to attach parameters with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I got a problem using dapper to attach parameters to my MySql queries. 
Now this may be a noobish problem, but I've beaten my head on this for the better part of 2 hours now and it's still not working.

My problem is with the SelectWithParametersTest() function right in the middle.  Here is what I've got...

EDIT: Ok more details.
The actual Mysql server throws fits and says, "ERROR [07001] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters".

The actual exception gets caught at QueryInternal`<T`>(...) on the line where it's executing the reader.  (using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

When I inspect the command there are no parameters attached to it, but the param object (that was passed to the function) has my anon object in it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dapper;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dapperExample = new DapperExample())
        {
            //dapperExample.SelectTest();
            dapperExample.SelectWithParametersTest();
        }
    }
}

class DapperExample : IDisposable
{
    #region Fields
    IDbConnection _databaseConnection;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor / Destructor
    public DapperExample()
    {
        _databaseConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=MySqlServer;");
        _databaseConnection.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_databaseConnection != null)
            _databaseConnection.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods (Tests)
    public void SelectTest()
    {
        // This function correctly grabs and prints data.
        string normalSQL = @"SELECT County as CountyNo, CompanyName, Address1, Address2
                             FROM testdb.business
                             WHERE CountyNo = 50 LIMIT 3";

        var result = _databaseConnection.Query<ModelCitizen>(normalSQL);
        this.PrintCitizens(result);
    }

    public void SelectWithParametersTest()
    {
        // This function throws OdbcException: "ERROR [07001] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters"
        string parameterizedSQL = @"SELECT County as CountyNo, CompanyName, Address1, Address2
                                    FROM testdb.business
                                    WHERE CountyNo = ?B";
        var result = _databaseConnection.Query<ModelCitizen>(parameterizedSQL, new { B = 50 });
        this.PrintCitizens(result);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void PrintCitizens(IEnumerable<ModelCitizen> citizenCollection)
    {
        foreach (var mc in citizenCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--------");
            Console.WriteLine(mc.BankNo.ToString() + " - " + mc.CompNo.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(mc.CompanyName);
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Address1);
            Console.WriteLine(mc.Address2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    #endregion
}

public class ModelCitizen
{
    public long CountyNo { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not at a PC right now, but: what actually happens with that?

Comment: My bad: The actual Mysql server throws fits and says, "ERROR [07001] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log]SQLBindParameter not used for all parameters".

The actual exception gets caught at QueryInternal<T>(...) on the line where it's executing the reader.  (using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

When I inspect the command there are no parameters attached to it, but the param object is there.  Also thanks for the fast response Marc.

Comment: I will have to check, but it *looks* like MySql hates named parameters - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457597/mysql-rejecting-parameter . If that is accurate, then binding those could be a huge pain.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  The whole positional parameters vs named parameters would really suck to parse.  Personally I see the code and I still think the reflection stuff you're doing is black magic.  I'll try it again using the MySqlConnector driver instead of the ODBC and let you know if that fixes it.

Comment: Ok using MySqlConnectorNet 6.4.3 fixes one of my problems, but now causes others.  (Error parsing column 0 (CountyNo=50 - UInt32)).  I'll try to work that out for awhile and if I can't then I'll post a new question.

Comment: @Yokin is your property a `ulong` ?

Comment: I've never used dapper but I do know that for MySQL you need to specify that you'll be sending in parameters via connection string by adding "allow user variables=true;"

Comment: My property was a long when that error happened.  I then changed to a ulong and that threw another error so I switched it back.  I'm still getting the parsing error though.  The CountyNo field is a unsigned INTEGER in the database.  I've hammered at this thing for awhile now and can't see what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yokin, did you try using a UInt32 instead of long in the C# code?

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: How do I comment, I don't see a button (except on this comment)

Comment: The textbox doesn't show because there are too many comments, but below the comments, there's a button saying "add / show 3 more comments". Click on it, it will reveal the textbox